# Azure ML Import Data connection has special character in password

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Azure ML Import Data from Azure SQL DB connection has special character `]` in password.

In connection wizard it is successfully connected.

But when run the experiment, it gives error with no error message.

After long analysis this issue is identified.

Anyone knows how to escape character for Import Data functionality in Azure ML?

Comment: I am trying notify Azure ML team (MSFT) about this issue.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo Thanks